# newcolumntype leads to error with afterpage

Tags: tables, landscape, pdflscape

when I'm defining a new columntype in an afterpage environment, LaTeX fail with an error:

```
Latex Error: ./chapters/chapter3.tex:149 Illegal parameter number in definition of \AP@.
```

When removing the nowcolumntype declaration and replacing "C" with "p" it works, so it seems to be a problem with afterpage.

I'm using the pdflscape package

```
\afterpage{

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
    \newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|C{2.0cm}|C{2.0cm}}
        \hline
        1  1    &   1  2\\
        2  1    &   2  2\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{table}

\end{landscape} 
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a general principle, `\newcolumntype` declarations shouldn't be used outside a document's preamble. (The fact that using them outside the preamble doesn't result in a crash when not used in conjunction with the `afterpage` environment doesn't contradict this point...)

The following MWE, which is based on your code, compiles without errors. Note that I've replaced the `\begin{center}` ... `\end{center}` instructions with a simple `\centering` instruction and have loaded the `rotating` package to make use of its `sidewaystable` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{afterpage,array,rotating}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\begin{document}
\afterpage{%
\begin{sidewaystable}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|C{2.0cm}|C{2.0cm}|}
        \hline
        1  1    &   1  2\\
        2  1    &   2  2\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There's usually no problem in locally setting a `\newcolumntype` in a `table` environment. In this case I suspect a timing problem due to the fact that `\afterpage` plays with the output routine.

Comment: @egreg: I would still maintain that `\newcolumntype` should only be executed in the preamble. :-) However, I'll soften the phrasing in the answer to be less apodictic about this issue.

Comment: I had the same issue with `\newcommand` inside `table`; putting them out of `\afterpage` fixed the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Afterpage tokens are put through a `\def` (of a temporary macro who's name is shown in the error message) So as usual with a def you have to double the `#`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{afterpage,array,rotating}

\begin{document}
\afterpage{%
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{##1}}
\begin{sidewaystable}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|C{2.0cm}|C{2.0cm}|}
        \hline
        1  1    &   1  2\\
        2  1    &   2  2\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}
}
\end{document}
```

It would have been possible to define `afterpage` in a way that avoided the need to double the `#` (by cycling the tokens through a token register) but I didn't think anyone would ever use the package let alone need macro parameter tokens within its argument:-)